# WARN: Ignoring UDP error report ERROR when running a code in omnet++

Tags: omnet++, veins, inet

I'm using omnet++ to implement vanet and car communication via veins and inet. A few times when the cars send message to each other the message show error and in the console I see the following:

```
> ** Event #164460  t=21.549062614832  RoutingScenario.node[1].udp (Udp, id=82)  on ICMP-error-#7134-type3-code3 (inet::Packet, id=481750)
> 
> WARN: ICMP error received: type=3 code=3 about packet 10.0.0.73:1025 >
> 10.0.0.10:5000 DETAIL: Source socket is sockId=2, notifying.
> ** Event #164461  t=21.549062614832  RoutingScenario.node[1].app[0] (UdpBasicApp, id=85)  on ERROR (inet::Indication, id=481753)
> 
> WARN: Ignoring UDP error report ERROR
```

I don't understand the error and how can I solve it. I appreciate if anyone can suggest me a solution for it.

Answer (score 1):

This is totally normal, especially in a mobile network. ICMP error type 3 is "Destination unreachable". While this is called "ICMP Error", in fact this could be totally normal operation. That's why it is considered only a WARNING in the simulation.